# Media Session Compat: Pre-lollipop different lock screen behaviors

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I am working with `mediaSessionCompat` to present the current playing audio on the lock screen.

From lollipop all is well but on pre-lollipop I ran into the following issue on a Sony C6916 API 19

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the lock screen background has not changed. Instead, it has added the background I would have used for the lock screen as a image for the playing audio

I am aware that different Android devices will behave differently but does anyone know a way around this?

**Me adding the bitmap to Metadata**

```
  private void updateMediaSessionMetadataArtwork(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        mediaMetadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART, bitmap);
        mediaSession.setMetadata(mediaMetadataBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I am aware of the different data that can be passed `METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART` and `METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON` but my biggest concern is what if this overrides the desired lock screen background on devices that do allow it so I am uncertain what I can do here so any input would be much appreciated.

Please let me know in comments if you need more info about my implementation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but here is my observations whilst investigating

So after testing on a few pre-lollipop devices two from Sony and one from HTC.
I have come to the conclusion that the entire lock screen background cannot be replaced, instead it shows a thumbnail like the one in my opening post.

So what I do is check if it is pre-lollipop like so

```
     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
```

And then load in a different bitmap for the `MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART`

Oddly enough the changing of the lock screen background can also be device specific even on lollipop. I noticed my Samsung Tablet which has lollipop did not change the entire lock screen background either but just showed the notification.

I further verified this by checking the Spotify app in each case which I used as my control to check that I am on the right track